# Python 3 inheritance multiple classes with __str__

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, class, inheritance

How do I use multiple `__str__` from other classes? For example:

```py
class A:
    def __str__(self):
        return "this"

class B:
    def __str__(self):
        return "that"

class C(A,B):
    def __str__(self):
        return super(C, self).__str__() + " those"
        # return something(A) + " " something(B) + " those"

cc = C()
print(cc)
```

Output: **this those**

I would like the output to be: **this that those**

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance) is almost a solution (with `super()`)

Answer (score 7):

With multiple inheritance, `super()` searches for the *first* class that has the attribute, as they appear, from left to right. So, it will stop at `A`. You can access all the parent classes with the special `__bases__` attribute, and loop over them, calling `str` on each one.

Answer (score 2):

Call parent classes `__str__` methods explicitly:

```
class C(A, B):
    def __str__(self):
        return A.__str__(self) + ' ' + B.__str__(self) + ' those'
        # or return '{} {} those'.format(A.__str__(self), B.__str__(self))
```

Answer (score 1):

*I tried adding this code example to the blue_note answer but he reverted the change so reposting as an answer.*

Direct `super()` invocations don't quite work here with multiple inheritance.  It'll stop at the first found `__str__` method. Instead you can call all the parent `__str__` methods by iterating over `__bases__`.  Keep in mind, this will return the `object` type as well. Which may or may not be desired.

Example:

```
def __str__(self) -> str:
    bstr = ""
    for base in type(self).__bases__:
        bstr += base.__str__(self) if base.__name__ != 'object' else ""
    return bstr
```